# SQL check if value exists and return primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two tables, customer and application, both have primary keys (customerID and applicationID), application has a foreign key of customerID.

When a user starts an application it adds the customerId to the application table with some other information.

What I want to do is write a sql query/stored procedure that first checks if that customerId is already in the application table and if it is don't add it again, but update the information and return the applicationId for me to use.

Then if it is not in the table, add the customer id and information and return me the applicationID.

My code to add to the database is.

```
INSERT INTO Application (CustomerID, Q5, Q11a)  VALUES (@customerid,@q5, @q11a);" + "Select Scope_Identity()";

int applicationID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

How would I go about turning that into what I want it to do?

Comment: use the MERGE statement if you'r using 2008(r2) or 2012. if not, just start by a n update, check @@row_count if 0 then insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement in order to perform insert or update operation. After that you can just use `SELECT` statement in order to get the `ApplicationId`. The query would look like this:

```
MERGE Application AS target
    USING (SELECT @customerid,@q5, @q11a) AS source (CustomerID, Q5, Q11a)
    ON (target.CustomerID = source.CustomerID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Q5 = source.Q5, Q11a = source.Q11a
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (CustomerID, Q5, Q11a) VALUES (source.CustomerID, source.Q5, source.Q11a
);
SELECT ApplicationID FROM Application WHERE CustomerID = @customerid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Merge/Upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert)

Wikipedia Code:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_NAME USING table_reference ON (condition)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CustomerProc @CustomerID INT
    ,@AppId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM customer
            WHERE customerId = @CustomerID
            )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE customer
        SET /* fields to update */
        WHERE customerId = @CustomerID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO customer (
            customerId
            ,/* fields to insert*/
            )
        VALUES (@CustomerID /* values to insert*/);

        SELECT @AppId = customerId
        FROM customer
        WHERE customerId = @CustomerID;
    END
END
```

To call the proc from SSMS use `exec CustomerProc @CustomerID=/*number*/`

if you are using ADO.Net then try this:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string")){
conn.Open();
using(var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", conn)) { 
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@CustomerID",SqlDbType.Int);
   param.Value = /* your value */;
   param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 

   SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@AppId",SqlDbType.Int); 
   param2.Direction  = ParameterDirection.Output;

   command.Parameters.Add(param);
   command.Parameters.Add(param2);

   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

   Console.WriteLine(command.Parameters["@AppId"].Value); 
   }
}
```